# Import js file on browser side

Tags: javascript, import, client, dom-events, client-side

I want to import javascript file on client side, I have this file and I use **DOMContentLoaded and load events** to import a file to make a component. **I would like to be sure** if this way is proper or if it's bad or risky.

```
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', event => {
        Labo.insert({tagName: 'script', src: '/public/componentTest.js'}, 'head');
    });

    window.addEventListener('load', event => {
        Labo.insert(componentTest('text of my component'), 'body');
    });
```

Comment: what type of file ?

Comment: Like in the example, a javascript file

Comment: you can use ajax with jquery getScript() for example or you can use simply require() it depend in your need

Comment: I don't want to use any framework, i just want to be sure if these two events are enough. I insert a script tag in <head> to import the file when DOMContentLoaded is triggered. And I insert my virtual DOM when load is triggered.